# wampserver 2.0 is not working watching blank page

Tags: php, wampserver

My Wamp server 2.0 is not working i am only watching blank page in browser after typing http://localhost i reinstalled Wamp server also  but got no progress it is not working still.

Comment: Does the WAMP server icon turn to full white? Or does it have any part of it either red or yellow?

Comment: Are you using Skype? Or any other software for that matter which uses port 80?

Comment: it should be full white, have you restarted all services?

Comment: @ImranAli If it's yellow that means one of the services have failed to start. Click on the WAMP icon -> Select Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80. This will show you whether port 80 is used by anything else. Usual suspect is Skype

Comment: yes i restarted all services also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skype** and **WAMP** Server have long years of rivalry for port 80. Or in your case the problem could be that or any other software is listening in port 80. Another very potential match could be **Microsoft IIS**.

[Check this link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-check-and-identify-which-application-is-listening-or-opening-port-80-and-443-on-windows/) to see how you can identify which application is using port 80 and kill that.

Or alternatively, you can [make WAMP use another port](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,13744,65856).

Also, [you can make Skype not use port 80](http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/).

Comment: Just a note, You can stop Skype from using port 80 in the options

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution is to start wamp before skype starts.
This would allow wamp to capture port 80 before skype does. And skype would use some other port for communication.

This solution would work if you turn off skype while starting wampserver and turn it on after wampserver is working. (i.e. the icon in systray is green ).